# ERB showing through in multipart e-mail using HAML and ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, actionmailer, erb

I'm trying to build a multipart e-mail using Rails 3 ActionMailer and HAML. I'm not sure if it's the naming convention or what the issue is, the HAML part of the view is being rendered correctly, but the plain text (with ERB) is not. I'm seeing actual ERB code in the plain text version of my outbound emails.

I have the following files defined:

```
app/views/layouts/email.html.haml
app/views/layouts/email.text.erb
app/views/user_mailer/password_reset_instructions.html.haml
app/views/user_mailer/password_reset_instructions.text.erb
```

My mailer looks like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :application
  helper :user_mailer
  layout "email"

  #layout "email"
  # single method for either a password reset or initial account activation
  def password_reset_instructions(user)  
    setup_email(user)
    user.reload
    subject = (user.confirmed? ? "Password Reset Instructions" : "New Account Information")  
    @user = user
    @edit_password_reset_url = url_for(  :controller => "password_resets", 
                                      :id => user.perishable_token,
                                      :action => 'edit',
                                      :host => "#{user.subdomain}.#{Assignr::HOST_NAME}")
    @assignor_name = user.creator ? user.first_last_name : 'Your assignor'
    @site = user.site
    mail :to => @setup[:to], :from => @setup[:from], :subject => @setup[:subject] + subject    
  end

  protected
    def setup_email(user)
      # send to one or both e-mail addresses
      user.reload
      recipients = []
      recipients << user.first_last_name + " <" + user.email + ">" if user.email 
      recipients << user.first_last_name + " <" + user.email2 + ">" if user.email2 
      @recipients  = recipients.join(", ")
      @setup = {:to => @recipients, :from => email_address_for(user) , :subject => "assignr.com: "}
      @user = user
    end

    def email_address_for(user)
      "assignr.com <#{user.site_id}-#{user.id}@email.#{Assignr::HOST_NAME}>"
    end

end
```

My ERB plain text version looks like this:

```
<% if @user.confirmed? -%>
A request to reset your password has been made.
If you did not make this request, simply ignore this email.
If you did make this request just click the link below:
<% else -%>
An account with assignr.com has been created for you by <%= @user.creator ? @user.creator.first_last_name : 'your assignor'%>. 

assignr.com is a web-based service used to help referee and umpire assignors with game scheduling.  

Please visit the following URL to begin:
<% end -%>

<%= @edit_password_reset_url %>

If the above URL does not work try copying and pasting it into your browser.
If you continue to have problem please feel free to contact us.

<% if !@user.confirmed? and @upcoming_game_count > 0 %> 
<%= @user.creator ? @user.creator.first_last_name : 'Your assignor'%> has assigned you to <%= pluralize( @upcoming_game_count, 'game') %>, beginning <%= humanize_time(@next_game.date) %>.  To view detailed information on these assignments, you will need to click the URL above and follow the on-screen instructions to register.  
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "footer"%>
```

The actual multipart delivered e-mail looks like this (note the ERB code in the generated email):

```
Delivered-To: <snip>
Received: by 10.216.163.14 with SMTP id z14cs47630wek;
        Mon, 7 Feb 2011 06:21:54 -0800 (PST)
Received: by 10.142.141.16 with SMTP id o16mr4281923wfd.390.1297088513239;
        Mon, 07 Feb 2011 06:21:53 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <snip>
Received: from assignr.com (email.assignr.com [0.0.0.0])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id g39si10275834yhd.193.2011.02.07.06.21.52
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=RC4-MD5);
        Mon, 07 Feb 2011 06:21:53 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of <snip> designates 0.0.0.0 as permitted sender) client-ip=0.0.0.0;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of snip designates 0.0.0.0 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=snip
Received-SPF: pass (assignr.com: domain of snip designates 127.0.0.1 as permitted sender) receiver=assignr.com; client-ip=127.0.0.1; helo=localhost.localdomain; envelope-from=snip; x-software=spfmilter 0.97 http://www.acme.com/software/spfmilter/ with libspf2-1.0.0;
Received: from localhost.localdomain (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
        by assignr.com (8.14.4/8.14.3) with ESMTP id p17ELhYP013916
        for <snip>; Mon, 7 Feb 2011 09:21:43 -0500
Date: Mon, 07 Feb 2011 09:21:43 -0500
From: "assignr.com" <snip>
To: Jeff Wigal <snip>
Message-ID: <4d4ffff7d072_362b55b3bbe40347@assignr.com.mail>
Subject: assignr.com: Password Reset Instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_4d4ffff6d6fb6_362b55b3bbe4000";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



----==_mimepart_4d4ffff6d6fb6_362b55b3bbe4000
Date: Mon, 07 Feb 2011 09:21:43 -0500
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <4d4ffff78acc_362b55b3bbe40119@assignr.com.mail>

<% if @user.confirmed? -%>
A request to reset your password has been made.
If you did not make this request, simply ignore this email.
If you did make this request just click the link below:
<% else -%>
An account with assignr.com has been created for you by <%= @user.creator ? @user.creator.first_last_name : 'your assignor'%>.
assignr.com is a web-based service used to help referee and umpire assignors with game scheduling.
Please visit the following URL to begin:
<% end -%>
<%= @edit_password_reset_url %>
If the above URL does not work try copying and pasting it into your browser.
If you continue to have problem please feel free to contact us.
<% if !@user.confirmed? and @upcoming_game_count > 0 %>
<%= @user.creator ? @user.creator.first_last_name : 'Your assignor'%> has assigned you to <%= pluralize( @upcoming_game_count, 'game') %>, beginning <%= humanize_time(@next_game.date) %>.  To view detailed information on these assignments, you will need to click the URL above and follow the on-screen instructions to register.
<% end %>
<%= render :partial => "footer"%>


CIM Test Site

=======================================
assignr.com
Referee and Umpire Assigning Made Easy


----==_mimepart_4d4ffff6d6fb6_362b55b3bbe4000
Date: Mon, 07 Feb 2011 09:21:43 -0500
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <4d4ffff7b0aa_362b55b3bbe4023d@assignr.com.mail>

<html>
<body>
<style media='screen' type='text/css'>
a { color: #39B2E5; font-weight: bold; }
a:hover { color: #0a97d2; }
p, ul { font: 13px 'Lucida Grande', Lucida Grande, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; color: #56594c; }
h2 { font: 18px 'Lucida Grande', Lucida Grande, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: #56594c; }
h3 { font: 14px 'Lucida Grande', Lucida Grande, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #56594c; }
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden;   }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
</style>
<div style='padding: 10px; background-color:#ececdf;'>
<table style='margin-bottom: 10px;' width='100%'>
<tr>
<td align='center'>
<img alt='assignr.com' height='50' src='http://assignr.com/images/assignr_com_logo_50.png' width='136'>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table style='background: #fff;padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e7e0;' width='100%'>
<tr width='100%'>
<td style='background:#617494;height: 10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr width='100%'>
<td style=' padding: 20px 0px'>
<h2>
Hi
Jeff,
</h2>
<div style="width: 100%; font: 13px 'Lucida Grande', Lucida Grande, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding-right: 10px; color: #56594c;">

.. assume valid HTML goes here.

<p>
Follow
<a href='http://twitter.com/assignr'>assignr.com on Twitter</a>
<br>
Keep up with the latest news
<a href='http://dropkickstudios.com?utm_source=outbound-email'>on our blog</a>
<br>
Share your
<a href='http://assignr.zendesk.com/forums?utm_source=outbound-email'>questions and feedback</a>
<br>
View
<a href='http://twitter.com/assignr'>assignr.com system status</a>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr width='100%'>
<td style='background:#617494;height: 10px;'>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr width='100%'>
<td>
<p style='font-size: 11px; color: #b7b9ad; padding-top: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #f5f7f0; '>
Want to modify your assignr.com email address? Visit your
<a href='https://assignr.com/login?utm_source=outbound-email' style='font-weight: normal;'>settings</a>
page.
<br>
assignr.com is a trademark of Dropkick Studios, LLC, all rights reserved.  
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>


----==_mimepart_4d4ffff6d6fb6_362b55b3bbe4000--
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: Not sure what I did, but it seems to be working now... updated to latest version of Haml but I'm not sure that was the problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem -- except I'm using haml. Another oddity is all of my other mailers are working. It's just one in particular that's rendering my view source.